# Filter --help command?

Tags: command-line, search, documentation

Sometimes I want to search/filter help for particular commands for keywords.

```
history --help
```

gives list of options, sometimes it's overwhelming how much info is there. Can I filter it for keywork "clear" e.g.

```
history --help *clear*
```

Also sometimes I want all info from --help, but it's so long that some of the lines get lost and I cannot scroll up for them. How can I make it show screen by screen e.g. fill first screen then on key press fill second screen etc.

Question same for file listing command.

Answer (score 3):

`--help` is not a universal command (it's an argument to the command being called, and has to be provided explicitly by it), so there is no universal solution (in fact, `history` has no `--help` option on my system). You probably want something like `history --help 2>&1 | grep -E '(^|[^[:alnum:]])clear'` (the redirection is necessary for some commands that print their help/usage text on `STDERR`.

You could make this into a function like so:

```
helpgrep() {
    [ "$#" -eq 2 ] || return 1
    "$1" --help 2>&1 | grep -E "(^|[^[:alnum:]])$2"
}
```

Then run it with `helpgrep command search-string`.

As for your second issue, try piping it to `less` (or `more` if `less` is not available), for example, `history --help | less`.

Answer (score 0):

To view the commands that have `clear` in them you could use `grep`:

```
history | grep clear
```

If the output is long you can view it on a page-page basis using pipe the output thru `more`:

```
 history | more
```

Of course you can combine these

```
history | grep clear | more
```

This is not specific to just `history` so can be applied to any other command where you want to filter results and/or view ouptut a screen height at a time.

Answer (score 0):

`history --help | grep clear` shows you the lines that contain the word (or part of a word) `clear`. This is a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), where the output of the first command (`history --help`) becomes the input of the second command (`grep clear`, and [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) is a command to search for a pattern in some text). You can also browse the whole help by running `history --help | less` ([`less`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29) is a text file viewer) and use the <kbd>/</kbd> key in less to search for `clear`.